# imwheel does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11

I need to accelerate mouse wheel with imwheel, but it does not work - it shows XError:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied).

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and Arch Linux (kernel 5.10.11).

~/.imwheelrc :

```
".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 5
None,      Down, Button5, 5
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

Command:

```
imwheel -d --debug --kill

OR:
sudo imwheel -d --debug --kill
```

Output:

```
...
Grab buttons!
Grabbing Button 4...
Grabbing Button 5...
Grabbing Button 6...
Grabbing Button 7...
Grabbing Button 8...
Grabbing Button 9...
starting loop...
XError: 
    serial      : 12
    error_code  : 10
    request_code: 28
    minor_code  : 0
    resourceid  : 365
    error string: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
XError: 
    serial      : 13
    error_code  : 10
    request_code: 28
    minor_code  : 0
    resourceid  : 365
    error string: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and at least for me, adding `-b "45"` flag so that it *only* grabs the scroll wheel resolved the issue.

[Relevant ArchWiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMWheel#Back/forward_buttons_not_working).